# Android gradle build shows IllegalStateException: Duplicate key com.android.tools.idea.res.LayoutDataBindingInfo@6ea6bbc

Tags: android

I am using android DataBinding library it compiled successfully when i try to build to the emulator it can not run. Gradle build get fail and Gradle console shows

**IllegalStateException: Duplicate key com.android.tools.idea.res.LayoutDataBindingInfo@6ea6bbc**